# postfix/smtp[9475]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out

Tags: email, server, zimbra

I have a case on the zimbra mail server.Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? Thanks a lot

Jun 21 04:40:28 instance-1 postfix/smtp[9475]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 21 04:40:28 instance-1 postfix/smtp[9474]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 21 04:40:28 instance-1 postfix/smtp[9475]: 7CAF670750EC: to=****@gmail.com, relay=none, delay=50762, delays=50612/0.02/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jun 21 04:40:28 instance-1 postfix/smtp[9474]: 50D2C7074D97: to=****@gmail.com, relay=none, delay=84589, delays=84439/0.04/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out)

I have a case on the zimbra mail server.Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you opened outbound firewalls for tcp/25 to 64.233.171.26 and 64.233.171.27? Can you telnet to tcp/25 on those addresses from the affected machine?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by changing the mail relay port